Moving from Python 2.7 telnetlib to Python 3 telnetlib3 - asyncio causing lots of confusion
I am trying to update some very simple automation scripts I wrote in Python 2.7 to Python 3.xx. The devices are rather basic and only support telnet connections. I was using telnetlib in Python 2.7. What I learned was telnetlib is being deprecated and apparently replaced by telnetlib3 when using Python 3.
I am having a hell of a time trying to understand how to do a very basic telnet interaction with telnetlib3. Below is an example of what I am currently doing. telnetlib3 seems to make the below code significantly more complicated and over my head.
Any guidance would be appreciated. I cannot find a 'simple' send command and read results example anywhere.
import telnetlib

#Variables
telnetConnection = None
password = "password"

#Open connection
try:
    telnetConnection = telnetlib.Telnet('192.168.1.123', 23, 5)
except Exception:
    print "UNABLE TO CONENCT"

#Send/Recieve Commands
if telnetConnection != None:
    #Send 'ACCESS' command
    telnetConnection.write("ACCESS" + "\r" + "\n")

    #Wait for 'Passord: ?' prompt
    telnetConnection.read_until("Password: ?", 10)

    #Send password
    telnetConnection.write(password + "\r" + "\n")

    #Wait for '=>' prompt
    passReturn = telnetConnection.read_until("=>", 10)

    #Check to make sure password was accepted
    if 'Invalid Password' in passReturn:
        print 'Invalid password'
    else:
    #Send 'CLEAR' command
    telnetConnection.write("CLEAR" + "\r" + "\n")

    #Wait for '?' prompt
    telnetConnection.read_until("?", 10)

    #Send 'Y' command
    telnetConnection.write("Y" + "\r" + "\n")

    #Wait for '=>' prompt
    telnetConnection.read_until("=>", 10)

    #Close connection
    telnetConnection.close()

I cannot fund a single example of a simple call/response for telnetlib3.
The new 'forced' asyncio part is going to make moving to Python3 verify difficult. I am going to have to completely re-write my scripts as I am already using threading to process multipole devices at once.

I don't understand, they even have Quick example on their homepage: https://telnetlib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#quick-example

@Andrej-kesely that "quick" example is not very useful. At least not for one just getting started. I am in the exact same boat trying to do nearly the exact same thing. It's this line:

telnetlib.Telnet(...)
that doesn't have a "simple" counterpart in tl3. I can't find anything in their docs (or anywhere else FTM) that shows how to connect to a device, send a simple cmd, and then just capture the response. My script doesn't need to sit there and talk to the thing (necessarily) for seconds on end, I just need to ask it for some basic metadata, like its make/model (or whatever).

